# EXCEL How to return most recent nonblank cell in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have a spreadsheet with many columns and rows of data. In column BC I have nonblank cells sporadically based on other conditions. I am trying to find the row or cell reference for the last nonblank cell.

I have developed the following:

=IF(BC300="","",MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("'"&"CopCrv'!BC"&(M301-250)):BC300)),ROW(INDIRECT("'"&"CopCrv'!BC"&(M301-250)):BC300)),0))

cell M301 is the number 300, M300 is the number 299 and so on. When I use MAX(IF(... I get a result of 50 and when I use MIN(IF(... I get 0.

The range since the last nonblank cell will vary, in this particular instance, there is data in cell BC296 and BC262. Ultimately I should be getting the answer of 296 or BC296.

Basically I have created another column off to the right to record a running cell reference. The cell with information prior to cell BC300 is BC296. My formula will remain in cell BI301 and so on to continue to find cells that have data in them. Each time there is data in a cell, I am creating another IF formula to act on that particular piece of data. The next cell with data in it is BC318. When the formula I am trying to create in cell BI318 reacts this time, it should return BC300 as it was the cell with information prior to this cell.

I appreciate all assistance and feel free to ask follow up questions. Thanks!

Comment: Delete your comment please. Because I just edited your question to include it in there (which is what you should do in situations like this).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the row use MATCH:

```
=MATCH(1E+99,BC:BC)
```

This will return the last row in Column BC that has a number.

You can then concatenate that to get an Address:

```
="BC" & MATCH(1E+99,BC:BC)
```